# Unable to verify encrypted file signature

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Using Kleopatra, I have geneated two sets of keys to sign and encrypt a file:

- Set A:

  - Public  key : PA
  - Private Key : PRA
- Set B:

  - Public  key : PB
  - Private Key : PRB

I have used (PA) of Set A and for signature, (PRB) in Set B. This process executed successfully and generated an encrypted file.

However, when trying to verify the signature and decrypt/verify the files with Kleopatra, I get the following results:

> The file was decrypted but not validated the signature.
>
> test.text.asc -->test.txt: Not enough information to check signature validity.
>
> Signed on 2012-03-23 07:49 by test@test.com (Key ID :xxxxxxx).
>   The validity of the signature cannot be verified.

What’s wrong? Please advise if I am missing any settings.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't have the public key of Set B (PB) in your keyring of Set A. Thus, gnupg won't be able to know if it was really a good signature from that key.
Without you having PB, the signature will just "look like" it has been signed by the key with the key id of 0xXXXXXXXX, but it lacks the PB to check it thoroughly.

You might encounter this issue with Kleopatra, and the solution is to set the trust of the public key before verifying. Even if you have the correct public key for the signed file/message, the response from the application will show as not valid unless the public key is trusted.